# Faster Memory in a slower laptop?

Tags: memory, netbook

I recently upgraded the memory in my laptop from 2x2GB to 2x4GB (DDR2-800 PC2-6400). I'd like to use one of the 2GB SODIMMs in my stepson's Acer Aspire One netbook, which can take DDR2-667 PC2-5300, but I'm not sure if it would be able to use it at all. Anybody have any counsel?

Comment: With info provided, who knows, but as long as the RAM fits, you might as well try. It won't of course run at the faster speed, it will clock down to the existing RAM. It will either work, or it won't, you'll know right away.

Comment: After watching how difficult it is to access the SODIMM slot in an Acer Aspire One (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-EfzckyZMTk), I'm letting him deal with his slow netbook. I'm just not that good with breaking down and re-assembling; the memory replacement in my laptop was much more straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just try it? Nothing can go wrong... :)

<sub>We can't really just tell by the laptop name, I belief it would work but I could be wrong.</sub>

Comment: Do remember though, it is a netbook. There are limitations to it, and most don't go over 1-2GB from what I've read.